# JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) at line response.json()

Tags: json, python-3.x, python-requests

I am getting error Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) on the line response.json().

**WHAT I TRIED**

As opposed to other answers I do not get an error at json.loads() but at response.json().I have also tried tweaking response data body but no help.Here is the code.

```
import requests
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup


def get_links(search_name):
   search_name = search_name.replace(' ', '+')
   response = requests.get("http://www.google.com/search", 
          params={'q': search_name, 'first': 0}, 
          headers={'User-Agent': user_agent})
   dataform = response.json()
   page = json.loads(dataform)
   new_soup = Soup(page[1][1], 'lxml')
   images = new_soup.find_all('img')
   links = [image['src'] for image in images]
   return links
```

traceback:

```
<ipython-input-27-8d351939888e> in get_links(search_name)
 17               params={'q': search_name, 'first': 0},
 18               headers={'User-Agent': user_agent})
 ---> 19     dataform = response.json()
 20     page = json.loads(dataform)
 21     new_soup = Soup(page[1][1], 'lxml')

 /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/requests/models.py in json(self, **kwargs)
890                     # used.
891                     pass
--> 892         return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
893 
894     @property

/usr/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py in loads(s, encoding, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
352             parse_int is None and parse_float is None and
353             parse_constant is None and object_pairs_hook is None and not kw):
--> 354         return _default_decoder.decode(s)
355     if cls is None:
356         cls = JSONDecoder

/usr/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py in decode(self, s, _w)
337 
338         """
--> 339         obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
340         end = _w(s, end).end()
341         if end != len(s):

/usr/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py in raw_decode(self, s, idx)
355             obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
356         except StopIteration as err:
--> 357             raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
358         return obj, end

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `response.json()` attempts to decode whatever JSON that was sent as the response of the request. But obviously, *https://www.google.com* does not return json; it responds with a html instead.

This is evident from `response.text`, which shows the returned html as a string.

If you use a url which responds with actual JSON, example *https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1*,  then you will not get any error.